# Throw exception when second instance is created

Tags: java, inheritance, hierarchy

I recently came across this question and have not been able to find a solution to it. I hope I will get a convincing answer here.

Question : Let A be a non abstract class which is extended (separately) by two classes B and C. Now the task is to allow only one instance of the these classes to be created. If the client code tries to create a second instance of any of these classes, then an exception should be thrown.

```
A obj11 = new A(); // Fine.

A obj12 = new A(); // thrown an exception. 

B obj21 = new B(); // OR 

A obj21 = new B(); // both these should be fine
```

But shouldn't allow 2nd instance of class B to be created.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. : This is different from singleton.

Comment: So you should have only one instance of either A, B, or C? Or at most one of each?

Comment: No. At max one instance of A, one instance of B and one instance of C. If client tries to create second instance of any of these classes, then throw an exception.

Comment: Checks for `B` and `C` are easy to implement. Checks for `A`, on the other hand, are more difficult, as creating `B` or `C` means the constructor for `A` will also be called... Not sure if what you want is possible without you hard-coding the instances to use (a la singletons), because instantiating the subclasses means the superclass will also be "instantiated", but perhaps something involving `getClass()` shenanigans would work.

Comment: You should use Object pool check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

Comment: Rightly pointed out user3580294. If anyone extends B or C then the check in place for these classes will not work.

Comment: When constructing an object, we can not have visibility on references.

Comment: Are you allowed to use factory methods instead of constructors?

Comment: Only using constructor.

Comment: (I find it difficult to imagine why this would be wanted, or how it could be part of a sensible design.)

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it.  In the real world there should be some `synchronized` keywords.  All crammed into one file for simplicity.

```
public class A {

   static HashSet<Class> thereCanBeOnlyOne = new HashSet();

   public A() {
      Class c = this.getClass();
      if (thereCanBeOnlyOne.contains(c))
         throw new RuntimeException();
      thereCanBeOnlyOne.add(c);
   }



   static public class B extends A {}

   static public class C extends A {}


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a1 = new A();
      B b1 = new B();  // OK
      C c1 = new C();  // OK

      C c2 = new C();   // throws exception

   }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten some angle brackets at the end of `Class` and `HashSet`

Comment: While I realize you were trying to answer the question as stated, the question itself is just going to bring out all kinds of abusive oop anti-patterns.

Comment: @user3580294 depends on which Java you are using and your compiler settings.  Add them if you need to.

Comment: @spudone  Agree completely, I don't think I would ever really do something like this.  Sotiros, thread safety is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)    I did mention need for synchronization (or use a thread-safe collection).

Comment: idk about that... Either you'll get a compiler error with `<Class>` or you'll get a raw type warning. I'd say add them, as there really isn't much reason to not use generics these days (unless Java 1.4 and earlier is more widespread than I thought)

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok for you?

```
public class A {
  private static created = false;
  public static A create() {
    if (created) {
      throws new RuntimeException();
    } else {
      created = true;
      return new A();
    }
  }
  protected A() {
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  private static created = false;
  public static B create() {
    if (created) {
      throws new RuntimeException();
    } else {
      created = true;
      return new B();
    }
  }
  protected B() {
  }
}

public class C extends A {
  private static created = false;
  public static C create() {
    if (created) {
      throws new RuntimeException();
    } else {
      created = true;
      return new C();
    }
  }
  protected C() {
  }
}
```

You can create A, B, and C using:

```
A a = A.create();
B b = B.create();
C c = C.create();
```

Comment: I *think* this would work. Unfortunately, OP has said that only constructors can be used...

Comment: Sorry but this is not the solution I was hoping for.